# How do I check if specific child value exists in FireBase (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some trouble trying to check if user information is stored already in the FireBase database.
Basically I'm trying to do something stupid like this:
"select user_name from user where user_id="+userID+"
And if the nickname exists it should make the boolean var isFirstTime = false and if it doesn't it should stay true. And after that it should show register box or not.

This is my db:
[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25tNt.png)
And this is my code in onCreate method:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference dbRefFirstTimeCheck = databaseReference.child("User").child(user.getUid()).child("Nickname");

    isFirstTime = true;
    dbRefFirstTimeCheck.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                isFirstTime=false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    if(isFirstTime) {
        showNewUserBox();
    }
    else {

    }
```

No matter what I do, the methor showNewUserBox() is being called. How do I get the data i need and check if it's there?

Comment: callbacks are asyncronous. onDataChange or onCancelled will call asynchronously. So showNewUserBox will always be called

Comment: Firebase queries are always asynchronous and return immediately.  To learn more about that, read this blog: https://medium.com/@CodingDoug/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have commented, data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time you check `isFirstTime`, the data hasn't been loaded yet, `onDataChange` hasn't been run yet, so `ifFirstTime` will have its default value (`false` for a boolean).

All code that requires data from the database should be inside `onDataChange` (or invoked from within there). The simplest fix for your code is:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference dbRefFirstTimeCheck = databaseReference.child("User").child(user.getUid()).child("Nickname");

dbRefFirstTimeCheck.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            showNewUserBox();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Also see some of the many [questions about asynchronous loading from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-database%5d%5bandroid%5d%20asynchronous), such as [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519) (or this quite old classic: [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener/33204705#33204705)).