# Android Studio - Firebase onComplete called to soon

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I started working with android studio in less than a month, so i am pretty new to this.

I am working on a login system with Firebase Authentication, and with Firebase Database. My idea is that after the login is done and confirmed i send the user to one of two activities, and to check which one to send them to i check if they have already filled a quiz (witch is a boolean inside their database).

My problem is that my `onComplete` method runs first instead of my `quizChecked`. Thanks to my log prints i know that i get the right value, but since the `onComplete` runs first my boolean is always false...

How can i make the `onComplete` fire after the `quizResposta` method?

Thanks in advance!

Here are my main methods in this class:

```
 private boolean quizChecked() {

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

    myRef.child("user: " + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("quizChecked")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    if(snapshot.exists()) {
                        boolean a = snapshot.getValue(boolean.class);
                        if (a == true) { // if quiz is done

                            quizChecked = (boolean) snapshot.getValue();
                            Log.e("TAG", "here true: " + quizChecked);


                        } else {// if quiz not done
                            quizChecked = (boolean) snapshot.getValue();
                            Log.e("TAG", "here false or null: " + quizChecked);
                        }

                        Log.e("TAG", "AFTER quizChecked: " + quizChecked);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(Activity_Login.this, "No User!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e("onCancelled", " cancelled");
                }

            });

    Log.e("TAG", "________: " + quizChecked);

    return quizChecked;
}


private void loginVerification(String emailString, String passwordString) {

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailString, passwordString).addOnCompleteListener(
            this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {// if quiz answered -> MainActivity

                        quizChecked = quizChecked();

                        if (quizChecked == true) {

                            Log.e("TAG", "here true in login: " + quizChecked);

                            Toast.makeText(Activity_Login.this, "Login Sucess",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        } else { // if quiz not answered ->  activity_quiz

                            Log.e("TAG", "here false or null in login: " + quizChecked);

                            Toast.makeText(Activity_Login.this, "Login Sucess",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Login.this, Activity_Questionario.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        }
                        Log.e("TAG", "AFTER login: " + quizChecked);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Activity_Login.this, "Login Failure",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: can you call your quizchecked() in asyntask? and check its status on onPostExecute? You can show progress bar while quizchecked() is getting value https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: Your `return quizChecked` runs before `onDataChange`, because data is loaded from Firebsae asynchronously. There is no way to "fix" that. Instead, you should move all code that needs the data from the database **into** `onDataChange` (or call it from there). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900033/how-do-i-check-if-specific-child-value-exists-in-firebase-android/50901184#50901184 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks a lot for your reply! I got it know!