# check if an email exists before creating a user firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So the issue I am having is I have a registration form in which users enter information (which also contains an email).

I have an onClick method called

```
public void onCreateAccount(View view);
```

when the user clicks "Register", it validates the fields on the form.

```
public class Foo extends AppCompatActivity {
//OTHER PRIVATE MEMBERS
private EditText etEmail;
boolean isValid;
private DatabaseReference databaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //DOES SOME INITIALIZATION
}

public void onCreateAccount(View view){
   String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();

   if(validateEmail(email)){
      String id = databaseUser.push().getKey();
        User user = new User(id, email);
        databaseUser.child(user.getId()).setValue(user);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("isCreateAccount", true);
        startActivityForResult (intent,0);
   }
}

private boolean validateEmail(String email) {
   isValid = true; 
   databaseUser.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailUserEntered).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                                   isValid=false;

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
}
```

Before inserting the record into the firebase database, I want to first check if the email already exists prior to inserting. So a person typing email = a@mail.com would not allow so.

[image]

Comment: Did my answer help you @YusufJama ?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit refer to my comment in your answer below

Comment: @YusufJama follow this reference you will get help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893328/checking-if-a-particular-value-exists-in-the-firebase-database

Comment: Most likely you're struggling with the fact that data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. There is no way to simply return a boolean from `validateEmail`, since `onDataChange` fires after any `return` statement of `validateEmail`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50901184, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50435519

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this is my problem...so is there a work around which will allow me to first validate? is the simplest way just to put all my validation into this onDataChange method?

Comment: @YusufJama, FrankvanPuffelen is right. Since data is loaded asynchronously, you should directly do the work from inside the `if(dataSnapshot.exists())`. You should directly display the toast from there only.

Comment: Hi @YusufJama add your intent inside data change , because firebase query will take some time to get response , so check validation inside on dataChange  and take action according to it

Answer (score 0):

Stopping the user from logging in if such email exists should be simple and you may use a code like this to do so:

```java
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");

boolean flag=false;

databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailUserEntered).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                                       flag=true;

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
        return flag;
```

But if you want the user to be stopped from writing an email which is in database in mid-way, without authentication, it would be pretty difficult.

You'd have to run a check through the database letter by letter and not only this would decrease efficiency, it would be not so good looking at the end.

**EDIT:**

Data is loaded asynchronously from Firebase so you should be placing something like this right inside the `if(dataSnapshot.exists())` to avoid the issue you're facing right now.

```java
if(validateEmail(email)){
      String id = databaseUser.push().getKey();
        User user = new User(id, email);
        databaseUser.child(user.getId()).setValue(user);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("isCreateAccount", true);
        startActivityForResult (intent,0);
   }

else
  Toast(YourActivity.this, "Email already exists", LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an index on the email field. Then you can do a query to find by email.

That will improve performance as no need to loop through the children.

Something like:

```java
orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once('value').exist();
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, which makes it impossible to have a method like `boolean validateEmail(String email)` on Android. Loading data from the database would have to be a blocking operation to enable such a method, and Android doesn't allow blocking operations (as it would leave the phone inoperable).

So instead, you have to *either( move the code to create the user **into** `validateEmail` *or* pass in a custom interface that you then call once the result from the database is back. The code for that last one is below.

First we'll create a custom interface that you can implement anywhere where you need to check if a user already exists.

```
public interface UserExistsCallback {
  void onCallback(boolean value);
}
```

This interface can be as specific or generic as you want. It's very similar to Firebase's `ValueEventListener`, but this interface is just for your own use.

With this interface, we can define the `validateEmail` method like this:

```
private void validateEmail(String email, final UserExistsCallback callback) {
   isValid = true; 
   databaseUser.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailUserEntered)
       .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               callback.onCallback(dataSnapshot.exists())
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
               throw databaseError.toException();
           }
       });
}
```

And then invoke it from `onCreateAccount` like this:

```
public void onCreateAccount(View view){
   String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();

   validateEmail(email), new UserExistsCallback() {
      public void onCallback(boolean exists) {
         if (!exists) {
            String id = databaseUser.push().getKey();
            User user = new User(id, email);
            databaseUser.child(user.getId()).setValue(user);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("isCreateAccount", true);
            startActivityForResult (intent,0);
         }
      })
   }
}
```

Also see many of the (linked) answers below:

- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener/33204705#33204705)
- more [questions about async loading](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-database%5d%5bandroid%5d%20asynchronous)

Answer (score 0):

This method is for auth only: `firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail("emailaddress@gmail.com")`